# Assembly versions and locations when using System.Data.SQLite to generate ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, nuget, .net-assembly, system.data.sqlite

The context of my question is as follows:

- I have previously installed the System.Data.SQLite ADO.NET adapter available from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)
- Along with the assembly, I installed the Design Time Support for creation Entity Data Models from a SQLite database.
- When I installed the Design Time Support, the assembly version was `Version=1.0.79.0`
- Yesterday I started a new project and generated a data model from a SQLite database using the Design Time Support tools.
- For my project, I had to add references to the `System.Data.SQLite` and `System.Data.SQLite.Linq` assemblies. Here I chose to use Nuget to get the most recent version, as this simplifies updates during the rest of development. The latest assembly version, that fetched by Nuget, was `Version=1.0.81.0`

The project compiled, but upon execution gave me this error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.79.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Source=mscorlib
  FileName=System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.79.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139
```

I figured this was because the assembly version referenced by the Design Time Support tools was different from the version referenced by my project, and I was right. I downloaded the latest setup from the System.Data.SQLite site, reinstalled the Design Time Support, and recompiled the project. This solved my problem.

My question is:

1. Does this mean I cannot use the Design Time Tools provided with the System.Data.SQLite setup along with Nuget, as there will frequently be a mismatch between the old installed Design Time Support version and the latest assembly from Nuget? Or is there a way to update the Design Time support via Nuget, or better still, to compile the model using the latest assembly version, rather than whatever came with the Design Time Support (which I am guessing is in the GAC, which I know precious little about).